# How do I change different elements of the same with same member function?

Tags: c++, string, overloading

I am new to C++ and am not able to find the answer. This is the code I want to write:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee{
private:
    string name;
    string gender;
public:
    void display();
    void update(string);
    Employee(string a, string b){
            name = a;
            gender = b;
    };
    ~Employee(){};
};

void Employee::display(void){
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Gender: " << gender << endl;
    }

 void Employee::update(string a){
 /*
   a function that updates either the 
   name element or gender element
   based on which element it is used by.
 */
    }

 int main(){
    Employee employee1 ("Joe","Male");
    Employee employee2 ("Jon","Male");


    employee1.display();
    employee2.display();

    employee1.name.update("Mary");          // This is what I want to do: Same function
    employee2.gender.update("Female");      // for different elements of same type           

    employee1.display();
    employee2.display();

    return 0;
 }
```

How do I go about doing this?
I thought about function overloading but both elements are of the same type. I do not want to pass any extra values and make the code look crappy. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: "How do I change different elements of the same with same member function?" — *what?* ... edit: Ah well now, after reading everything I get it. But that question is... not well phrased.

Comment: In my opinion, the members are private, so you will not have access to them outside of your class. So You cannot use `employee.name` in your main...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use setters and getters like this:

```
void Employee::setName(const string &a) {
    this->_name = a; // validate or whatever you need to do
}

const string &Employee::name() const {
    return this->_name;
}

void Employee::setGender(const string &a) {
     // ....
}
```

Usage as one would expect

```
employee1.setName("Mary");
employee2.setGender("Female");
```

Comment: In getter you forgot a colon `:`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, because he wants to 'change different elements of the same with same member function'

Comment: @alain Yes it does. The way arpith's going is bad.

Answer (score 0):

The `basic_string` class already implements a 'setter':

```
employee1.name.assign("Mary");
employee2.gender.assign("Female");
```

If you want to access `name` and `gender` like you have written in your question, you need to make both `public`, as @sop correctly pointed out.

Comment: The members are private, so it is in vain the `employee1.name.assign("X");`